# When to use FieldDescribeOptions.FULL_DESCRIBE in SObjectField.getDescribe(options)?

Tags: apex, picklist, sobjectfield, enum

**Background**

Playing around with the [SObjectField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectField.htm#apex_Schema_SObjectField_getDescribe_2) class has led me down a rabbit hole in wondering why and how I can make use of the `getDescribe(options)` method where `options` is a [FieldDescribeOptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_Schema_FieldDescribeOptions.htm) enum value.

To me, it reads as if the platform is performing a method overload from `getDescribe()` to `getDescribe(FieldDescribeOptions.DEFAULT)` but what I am struggling to understand is why I would ever use `FieldDescribeOptions.FULL_DESCRIBE`.

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult result = Contact.CleanStatus.getDescribe();
System.debug(Json.serializePretty(result) + '\n');

Schema.DescribeFieldResult defaultResult = Contact.CleanStatus.getDescribe(FieldDescribeOptions.DEFAULT);
System.debug(Json.serializePretty(defaultResult) + '\n');

Schema.DescribeFieldResult fullDescribeResult = Contact.CleanStatus.getDescribe(FieldDescribeOptions.FULL_DESCRIBE);
System.debug(json.serializePretty(fullDescribeResult) + '\n');
```

All three debug statements produce the same result for a describe on the standard `Contact.CleanStatus` picklist. Salesforce does state "*For example, `AIConversationContext.PersonType` field is a picklist that contains a list of accessible object types.*".

**Questions**

1. What does it mean to have a picklist that contains a list of accessible object types?
2. What should I expect when using `getDescribe(FieldDescribeOptions.FULL_DESCRIBE)` over `getDescribe(FieldDescribeOptions.DEFAULT)`?
3. When will `getDescribe(FieldDescribeOptions.FULL_DESCRIBE)` return a value that differs from `getDescribe(FieldDescribeOptions.DEFAULT)`?

If somebody can answer the above 3 Qs that would be very helpful and if you have code examples, thats a bonus!

Comment: I don't know the answer, yet, but for now this is the best resource I found so far around the subject: https://www.ca-peterson.com/apex/2020/01/21/apex-describe-calls-what-you-need-to-know.html

Comment: #1: I think you are talking about [Entity Definition from Custom Metadata](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_relationships_create.htm&type=5).

Comment: Nice find on that link!